# Kotlin Reflection on Object Expression

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have a top level kotlin object with various constants declared in it. How can I iterate and reflect on those properties/fields?

```kotlin
object Foobar {
  val MEANINGFUL_CONSTANT = SomeClass(...)


  @JvmStatic
  val getConstants: List<SomeClass>
      get() {
            val props = Foobar::class.staticProperties
            return props.mapNotNull { property ->
                val p = property.get()
                if (p is SomeClass) {
                    p
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
      }
}
```

No matter what I put in for `Foobar::class.staticProperties`, I get an empty list back. How do I properly reflect on Foobar?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/static-properties.html) of `staticProperties`

> Only properties representing static fields of Java classes are considered static.

That is why `staticProperties` on `Foobar` isn't returning anything.

You can use `memberProperties` and have a condition to match the `KType` of `SomeClass` as below. Maybe that helps.

```kotlin
val getConstants: List<Any>
        get() {
            val props = Foobar::class.memberProperties
            val someClassType = SomeClass::class.createType()
            return props.mapNotNull { property ->
               if (property.returnType == someClassType) {
                   property.getter.call(this)
               } else {
                   null
               }
            }
        }
```